# How to execute Camunda BPMN workflow based on DMN rules

Tags: camunda

I want to create a rule-based automation system using Camunda DMN and BPMN.
I want this system built on these fundamental principles:
a) have business events flow through Kafka
b) have a standalone service examine each event's data
c) have each event's data evaluated against one or more rules encoded in Camunda DMN
d) have a Camunda BPMN workflow executed based in the results of DMN rule(s) evaluation

Example:
a) A Kafka topic contains massages from external customers requesting to purchase some items
b) A standalone service examines every message and evaluates it against a DMN rule, which requires for each request to contain the quantity of items being requested
c) A Camunda task examines each message's "Requested Item Quantity" field
d) If the "Requested Item Quantity" field does not contain a valid value, a corresponding Camunda "Request required item quantity from the customer" BPMN workflow is executed
e) The "Request required item quantity from the customer" BPMN workflow automatically sends an email to the customer, requesting to specify the required item quantity
f) When the reply arrives from the customer it is placed on the corresponding Kafka topic and is examined by a standalone service
g) When when the customer's response is matched with the original "pending" request, a corresponding Camunda BPMN "Fulfill Customer Request" workflow is executed and the original request is fulfilled.

Question: Is this entire scenario possible to accomplish bu utilizing Camunda DMN to define the rules and Camunda BPMN, with the BPMN workflows being triggered by the results of DMN rules evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

at the moment I'm working with the following tool stack:

- Apache Camel as REST endpoint and REST client
- Camunda BPMN engine

Camel is used, because one can make routing decisions for events without any complication. It is planned within our project to add another input channel from Kafka. The advantage of Camel is, that the new interface is not shown to the business process part. I use always the possibility to send Message events to launch processes or continue already running processes.

Camel uses queues which can be equiped with plugins to perform actions. I would use this feature to make up decisions with help of the DMN engine. Based on the result you can make up your routing decision within Camel and address your events to the appropriate process.

Keep in mind, that it is also possible to model a process which uses Business Rule Tasks implemented with DMN to make up the decisions. In this case you can forward the events to the appropriate process.

So check the requirements and select a solution which fits your needs.
Kind regards